# Updating formula inside a function

Tags: r, glm, r-caret

I am trying to write a function which will fit a glm and give me back some statistics:

```
library(caret)
library(marginalmodelplots)
data(MissAmerica08)
MissUSA <- MissAmerica08[,c(2,4,6,7,8,10)]

glm.binomial<-function(data,formula,num.trials,linkf="logit",
                       trctr=trainControl(method = "none"),conf.lvl=0.95)
{
result<-list()
lhs<-formula[[2]]
data[,"wghts"]<-rep(num.trials,length(data[,as.character(lhs)])) 
data[,as.character(lhs)]<-data[,as.character(formula[[2]])]/num.trials #so the vector is in [0,1]
fit<-train(form=formula,data=data,family=binomial(),method="glm", 
       trControl=trainControl(method = "none"), weights=wghts)
result[["Statistics"]] <- summary(fit)
}
glm.binomial(formula=Top10~.,data=MissUSA,num.trials=9)
```

My problem is that since I am putting wghts in the data frame when fitting the model the vector wghts also becomes an explanatory variable. Is it possible to modify the formula before putting it in train() so that wghts is not in the model? Or alternatively can I store wghts somewhere else? I was also thinking of putting an if(formula[[3]]=='.') and substituting '.'with all other factors however I am not sure how to do that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would put a logical check and update the formula using the `update` function. For example,

```
f1 <- y ~ a + b + w

myfun <- function(f, w) {
  if (is.vector(w)) {
    f <- update(f, ~ . - w)
  }
  return(f)
}

myfun(f = f1, w = 1:3)

[1] y ~ a + b
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Unfortunately this will not work if on the right hand side I have '.' instead of factors grouped together and this is my actual problem. If I have certain factors put in the formula my function works just fine however if '.' is present it breaks. Do you think there is another way to store wghts in the data frame without it being recognized as a factor?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that you need to do anything beyond using

```
glm.binomial(formula=Top10~.-wghts,data=MissUSA,num.trials=9)
```

Your call to `train` includes specifying `weights=wghts`. `train` uses the "standard convention" of a terms to create the design matrix and that is done independently of getting the vector of weights.

In case you are interested, here is a snippet from under the hood of `train.formula`:

```
<snip>
x <- model.matrix(Terms, m, contrasts, na.action = na.action)
cons <- attr(x, "contrast")
xint <- match("(Intercept)", colnames(x), nomatch = 0)
if (xint > 0) x <- x[, -xint, drop = FALSE]
y <- model.response(m)
w <- as.vector(model.weights(m)) 
res <- train(x, y, weights = w, ...)
<snip>
```

The object `x` here will contain whatever the rhs of the formula specified and `model.weights` works independently of this. (On a side note, I was trying to figure all this out during the early says of S+ and I wish someone had done walkthrough of this code to explain it back then. If it seems magical and vague... it is).

You should test the code above thought to make sure that it gives you the result that you expect. If so, I will make a note on the [caret website for train](http://topepo.github.io/caret/training.html) to show and example of using grouped binomial data with `glm` and `train`.

Thanks,

Max

Comment: Thank you for this insight. My function produces the same results as glm() so it works fine (it only needs `result` in the last line to ensure that the result is printed and trControl=trctr when train is called). My idea was for the function to remove wghts automatically instead of asking the user to manually subtract it however I was not able to change the formula and still make it recognizable by train().